# Multiply the elements inside the rows in parentheses by (-1)

Tags: python

Please tell me how to find elements starting with '(' and multiply them by (-1). So that the positive and negative elements (with parentheses that) are preserved in the new list
Initial:

```
['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332', '-', 'sdgfsv', '(5 845 264), '-']
```

Final:

```
[2342746, -4836482, 7493332, -5845264]
```

My code:

```
my = ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332', '-', 'sdgfsv', '(5 845 264)', '-'] 
def test(data: str):
   if num := ''.join(filter(str.startswith('('), data)):
        return int(num) * (-1)
   if num := ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, data)):
        return int(num)
    
test1 = list(map(test, my))
print(test1)
```

I understand that in the first if only the index is returned and not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using regex.

```
import re 
a = ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332', '-', 'sdgfsv', '(5 845 264)', '-']  
b = []

for v in a:
  w = v.replace(' ','')
  x = re.findall(r'(\()?(\d+)(\))?',w)
  if x:
    if x[0][0] == '(':
      b.append(-1 * int(x[0][1]))
    else:
      b.append(int(x[0][1]))
print(b)
```

output

```
[2342746, -4836482, 7493332, -5845264]
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

```
my = ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332', '-', 'sdgfsv', '(5 845 264)', '-'] 
new_list = []
for item in my:
    if item.startswith("("): # a parentheses item
        new_item = -1 * int(item[1:-1].replace(" ", "")) # create negative,remove parentheses & cast to int
        new_list.append(new_item)
    new_item = item.replace(" ", "")
    if new_item.isnumeric(): #returns True if a string is numeric.
        new_list.append(new_item)
```

EDIT: added `replace(" ", "")` to the for loop to replace spaces with nothing and allow for proper int casting.

Comment: running this I get ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 836 482'``` python 3.8.13

Comment: @Nin17 sorry I've forget to replace the spaces. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with list comprehension:

```
[-1*int((i[1:-1])) if i.startswith("(") else int(i) for i in [j.replace(" ", "") for j in my] if i.isnumeric() or i.startswith("(")]
```

Output:

```
[2342746, -4836482, 7493332, -5845264]
```